# C++ Can friends classes access all of the members of its base class?

Tags: c++, friend

My understanding was that a friend class can access all of the members (including data members) of the base.  However, with this code:

```
class Animal {                                                                                                                                                                                            
  string _name;                                                                                                                                                                                           
  Animal(){};                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Animal(const string & n, const string & t, const string & w); 
  friend class Duck;                                                                                                                                                                                      
};                                                                                                                                                                                                        

Animal::Animal(const string & n) : _name(n) {                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                                                                         


class Duck: public Animal {                                                                                                                                                                               
public:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  Duck(const string n) : Animal(n){};                                                                                                                                                    
};                                                                                                                                                                                                        


int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  Duck donald("Donny");                                                                                                                                                                                   
  printf("The donlad ran %s\n", donald._name.c_str());                                                                                                                                                 
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                               
}
```

I get `error: '_name' is a private member of 'Animal'`

Why can't the `friend class Duck` access all the members of the base class `Animal`?

Comment: You don't have to make child class friend to its parent.

Comment: Sure, `Duck` can access all the members of `Animal`. But `main()` can't access them.

Comment: @AlexanderVX if I do not make `Duck` a friend, then I can not access the constructor from `Animal`

Comment: If you want an interface to only be available to child classes, declare it `protected` instead of `private`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is where you call `printf("The donlad ran %s\n", donald._name.c_str());` in `main`

You can't access `_name` via a class instance (`donald` in this case) because `_name` is `private`.  `_name` is accessible from within the `Duck` class because of the `friend` designation, but is not accessible in `main`

Answer (score 0):

1. `friend` has nothing to do with *inheritance*.
2. You get the error because `main()`, not `Duck`, is the one trying to access the private `_name` member of `Animal`.  Making `Duck` a `friend` of `Animal` grants access to `Duck`'s own methods, not to `main()`.